# Users that returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with [EVENT_DATE] and [USER_ID], I would like to know how to count the users who came back in the same month.

```
Table_01    
------------------------------------------- 
    EVENT_DATE          |   USER_ID
-------------------------------------------
2017-03-28 00:00:25.000 | 0006235012201
2017-03-04 23:00:00.000 | 0006235012201
2017-03-19 00:25:15.000 | 0006235012201
2017-02-03 10:00:02.000 | 0006235012202
2017-01-18 00:15:00.000 | 0006235012202
2017-03-28 11:00:15.000 | 0006235012202
2017-03-23 15:20:02.000 | 0006235012203
2017-02-18 12:00:06.000 | 0006235012203
2017-03-21 16:05:09.000 | 0006235012203
```

The answering being 2, because users 0006235012201 & 0006235012203 both came back within the same month.

EDIT: Sorry

I am looking to get the count by month.

```
-----------------------
Month | Users Returned
-----------------------
01/17 | 70
02/17 | 60
03/17 | 10
```

This is what I have, but it isn't correct as it seems to be listing users.

```
SELECT A.[USER_ID], A.[EVENT_DATE], COUNT(*)
FROM(
    SELECT [USER_ID], [EVENT_DATE], COUNT(*)
    FROM Table_01
    GROUP BY [USER_ID], [EVENT_DATE]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) A
GROUP BY A.[USER_ID], A.[EVENT_DATE]
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Compatibility level: SQL Server 2005 (90)

Answer (score 2):

```
select user_id
from your_table
group by user_id
having count(distinct year(event_date) * 100 + month(event_date)) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can get month wise result

```
 select month(EVENT_DATE),year(EVENT_DATE), USER_ID from tableName
 where  year(EVENT_DATE)=2017
 Group by USER_ID,year(EVENT_DATE),month(EVENT_DATE)
 Having HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

if you want some specific month wise you can add where condition like  month(EVENT_DATE) =3

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script

```
SELECT  DISTINCT USER_ID
FROM    Table_01
GROUP BY USER_ID, (YEAR(EVENT_DATE)*100)+MONTH(EVENT_DATE)
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get users returned in same month

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM #Table 
GROUP BY USER_ID,(YEAR(EVENT_DATE)*100)+MONTH(EVENT_DATE)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two levels of aggregation. First to get the users who have more than one row in a month. Then grouping by year,month to get the counts of users for a specific month.

```
select cast(mth as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(yr as varchar(4)) as mth,count(*)
from (select user_id,month(event_date) as mth,year(event_date) as yr
      from tablename
      group by user_id,month(event_date),year(event_date)
      having count(*) > 1
     ) t
group by cast(mth as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(yr as varchar(4))
```